# Where is the source code for built-in PHP functions located?

Tags: php, function, mamp

I have a local server installed on my Mac ([MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP)). Where can I find the PHP functions on my computer?

What is the path to the functions folder? For instance, `rand()`, `time()`, `isset()`, `explode()`.

I would like to see the code to learn from it.

Comment: Also see the **PHP Manual**. You can download it [here](http://www.php.net/download-docs.php).

Comment: https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/16/Understanding-PHPs-internal-function-definitions.html @Bona Chon

Answer (score 29):

You can download the PHP source from the page http://php.net/downloads.php.
Download and extract the archives. The standard functions are located under *ext/standard*.

Or simply browse them on GitHub: https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard