# PHP core files location

Tags: php

I need to understand better the ArrayAccess interface.
The documentation points to http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php but I would like to see the source code on my own for learning purposes. Where can I find it? 
On my debian there has to be this class.arrayaccess.php file somewhere right? in /etc/php/7.1 folder there are only .ini files.
On the official repo https://github.com/php I have no clue where it is. Am I missing something?
Thank you for your help

Comment: PHP is written in C, not in PHP. Can you obtain the information you want from C source code?

Comment: You have the code in the documentation, there is no mistery...Do you want to learn the PHP core or just PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the source code for built-in php functions located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859420/where-is-the-source-code-for-built-in-php-functions-located)

Comment: Furthermore, you normally install Linux software from binary packages. If you want the source code, you need to install a special source code package.

Comment: I wanted to see with my eyes on my machine the class.arrayaccess.php. Maybe alongside it there are other interfaces I may find useful to learn. Just to see how the core of php works but judging from the repo seems like too much advanced for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php is written in C, so if you want to know how functions work I suggest you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src) for the interpreter.

Comment: Yeah I took a look there already but I have 0 knowledge of C so I doubt I'll learn much. I completely ignored the fact that the main core of php was in C. I'm just a beginner. Thank you for you answer.